# Toggle Button Recyclerview Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, togglebutton

i've this issue made me crazy. When retrieved JSON data i will use this my adapter:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder) {
        final DomandaQuizTipo1 domandaQuiz1 = items.get(position);

        OriginalViewHolder vItem = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;

        /* Getting each answer from array of answer */
        Risposta1 risposta1 = domandaQuiz1.getRisposte().get(0);
        Risposta1 risposta2 = domandaQuiz1.getRisposte().get(1);
        Risposta1 risposta3 = domandaQuiz1.getRisposte().get(2);

        /* Get and set text of question */
        vItem.domanda.setTypeface(typefaceRegular);
        vItem.domanda.setText(domandaQuiz1.getDomanda());

        /* Get and set text of answer 1 */
        vItem.risposta1.setText(risposta1.getRisposta());
        vItem.risposta1.setTextOn(risposta1.getRisposta());
        vItem.risposta1.setTextOff(risposta1.getRisposta());

        /* Get and set text of answer 2 */
        vItem.risposta2.setText(risposta2.getRisposta());
        vItem.risposta2.setTextOn(risposta2.getRisposta());
        vItem.risposta2.setTextOff(risposta2.getRisposta());

        /* Get and set text of answer 3 */
        vItem.risposta3.setText(risposta3.getRisposta());
        vItem.risposta3.setTextOn(risposta3.getRisposta());
        vItem.risposta3.setTextOff(risposta3.getRisposta());

        /* When i click the first answer uncheck 2nd and 3rd */
        vItem.risposta1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.punteggiDomandeQuiz1[position] = items.get(position).getRisposte().get(0).getPunteggio();
                MainActivity.UpdatePunteggioTotale();

                vItem.risposta2.setChecked(false);
                vItem.risposta3.setChecked(false);

            }
        });
        /* When i click the second answer uncheck 1st and 3rd */
        vItem.risposta2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.punteggiDomandeQuiz1[position] = items.get(position).getRisposte().get(1).getPunteggio();
                MainActivity.UpdatePunteggioTotale();
                Log.d("adapterposition", "POS" + position);

                vItem.risposta1.setChecked(false);
                vItem.risposta3.setChecked(false);

            }
        });
        /* When i click the third answer uncheck 1st and 2nd */
        vItem.risposta3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.punteggiDomandeQuiz1[position] = items.get(position).getRisposte().get(2).getPunteggio();
                MainActivity.UpdatePunteggioTotale(); 
                vItem.risposta1.setChecked(false);
                vItem.risposta2.setChecked(false);

            }
        });


    } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}
```

My issue is this: in a recyclerview of each question that contains 3 answers to choose, when i click on one of answer (ex. first toggle button) is checked correctly but when i scroll recycler view i see other question with answer (ex. first toggle button) checked.

How can i avoid this issue? Take a look from this gif i putted below.

[Check gif this please to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ksl4.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a field like a selected (local not server) and check that's is selected and  change item ui

```
    if(vItem.selected==1)
        vItem.risposta1.setChecked(true);
    else  
        vItem.risposta1.setChecked(false);

    if(vItem.selected==2)
        vItem.risposta2.setChecked(true);
    else  
        vItem.risposta2.setChecked(false);
    if(vItem.selected==3)
        vItem.risposta3.setChecked(true);
    else  
        vItem.risposta3.setChecked(false);
    vItem.risposta1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.punteggiDomandeQuiz1[position].selected=1;
                notifyItemChange(adapterPosition);

            }
    });
    vItem.risposta2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.punteggiDomandeQuiz1[position].selected=2;
                notifyItemChange(adapterPosition);

            }
    });
    vItem.risposta3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.punteggiDomandeQuiz1[position].selected=3;
                notifyItemChange(adapterPosition);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the status of each toggle button in `onBindViewHolder`.
Something like:

```
vItem.risposta1.setText(risposta1.getRisposta());
//...
vItem.risposta1.setChecked(risposta1.isChecked());
```

Also when you update the data in the `OnClickListener` you have to notify the adapter:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hi Gabriele, thank you very much. I will try it later.